# How can WeChat API find WeChatID (not nickname) or alternative

Tags: integration, wechat

A client has a WeChat service account and would like to communicate with followers.  People may register on their website site for services without going through WeChat or by going through WeChat.  We would like a way to link WeChat and non-WeChat registrants, as we know that WeChat is their preferred communication method.  We can get followers from the WeChat API, and that gives us their OpenId, we could ask the non-WeChat users for their WeChat Id (not their nickname, as those are mostly in Chinese), but we can't find the way to match an OpenId with a WeChat Id.  Is there one?  Is there another way to match WeChat and non-WeChat registrants so that we can message them in WeChat?  Some different information we could ask the non-WeChat registrants for that would allow us to match? TIA.